# Swift move back button to Toolbar?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

In my project, I want to add back button in toolbar at the bottom of display.

I have my UIViewController embedded inside Navigation Controller, and also I have bottom toolbar. But back button is by default in top left part of navigation controller.

Comment: Why change what the Apple UI guidelines recommend?

Comment: Not mine desires, but I agree :/

Answer (score 1):

You cant move back button from navBat to toolbar, but you can add custom button.

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem( title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(gotoBack))
)
self.navigationController?.toolbar.items = items
```

and add to ViewController function

```
func gotoBack(){
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom navigationController

Swift 3.0

In `NavViewController.swift`

```
class NavViewController: UINavigationController,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var _delegate:UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _delegate = self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate
        self.delegate = self

    }



       func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
//Because it can slide
            if viewController != navigationController.viewControllers[0] {
                viewController.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil;  
            }else{
                viewController.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = _delegate;
            }
        }
    }
```

In NextViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func BackButtonItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let toolbar = UIToolbar (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
self.view.frame.size.width, height: 56))

    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    items.append(
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Viewcontroller.BackClicked(sender:)))
    )
    toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
    toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.black
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

self.navigationController?.toolbar.items = items

```
func BackClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem)

 {
  _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)   

 }
```